# This function test a bank card number with a specific prefix and length. My question in the code

Tags: javascript, function, loops, testing, chai

```
describe('Switch', function() {
  var expect = chai.expect;

  var prefixs = [4903, 4905, 4911, 4936, 564182, 633110, 6333, 6759];

  //iterate through every prefix in the list
  for (var i = 0; i < prefixs.length; i++) {
    //forming a 16 length number with this prefix using loop
    var prefix = prefixs[i].toString();
    var actual = prefix;
    for (var j = 0; j < 16 - prefix.length; j++) {
      actual = actual + '0';
      console.log(actual)
    }
// would actual be tested as 4903(first prefix), then 49030, then 490300, 4903000 ..ex or it will be tested when it is 16 charecters long only. please explain why.

    (function (actual, prefix) {
      it ('has a prefix of ' + prefix + ' and a length of 16', function() {
        expect(detectNetwork(actual)).to.equal('Switch');
      });
    })(actual, prefixs[i]);
});
```

// would actual be tested as 4903(first prefix), then 49030, then 490300, 4903000 ..ex or it will be tested when it is 16 charecters long only. please explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Once the prefix is 16 characters long.** 
Because your assertion is outside the inner for-each loop, it would have to wait for the inner for-each loop to end before the assertion is run.

if you wanted it to be assesed for each time you add an trailing 0 to your prefix, move it inside the inner foreach.

also, allow me to simplify your code a bit:

```
describe("Switch", function () {
  var expect = chai.expect;

  //iterate through every prefix in the list
  [4903, 4905, 4911, 4936, 564182, 633110, 6333, 6759].forEach((prefix) => {
    var actual = prefix.toString();
    for (var j = 0; j < 16 - prefix.length; j++) {
      actual += "0";
      console.log(actual);
    }
    it("has a prefix of " + prefix + " and a length of 16", function () {
      expect(detectNetwork(actual)).to.equal("Switch");
    });
  });
});
```

I just utilized the common JS foreach on the array, removed the uneccesary function around your assertion, and some small "tidying up".
hope it helps & answers your question :)

Comment: Thank you so much, it does make sense now.

Comment: @tammamtautou no worries :) if it solved your issues, please consider marking it as correct answer :)